# How to create a chrome extension that can run custom Catalon scripts on it?

Tags: katalon-studio

I am looking for a way to build a custom Chrome extension that runs Katalon scripts.

From their main page I am not sure how to process and execute the outputted commands posts:

```
 open  | https://katalon-test.s3.amazonaws.com/demo-aut/dist/html/form.html | 
 click | id=first-name | 
 type  | id=first-name | Alex 
 type  | id=last-name  | Smith
```

Comment: Can't you use the existing Katalon Recorder extension?

Comment: @MateMrše I want to, I am looking for a way to send some sort of command to the existing Katalon Recorder extension through my extension.